# Compilation map

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

Let assume a complex project (in C/C++), is there a solution to know which sources files are responsible/used for the creation of a specific binary without compiling the project itself.

I know I could just read the `Makefile` and try to follow the dependency chain like this but it's not very scalable and it could be hard if multiple Makefiles and / or implicit rules are used.

Thanks a lot for your help

PS: To clarify the first comments, I'm looking for a method which does *not* need to have a valid build environment (e.g. so compiling, even as a dry-run, is not an option).

Comment: Not really - only the compiler knows. What are you trying to do that prevents you from using the compiler for this?

Comment: What about running make in dry-run mode (-n or --dry-run)?  This will print out the commands that would have be run, but not run them, thus no compiler would be invoked.  From the output you should be able to determine which files are being compiled to make the executable.  As a plus you would get the command line for the compilations as well as the linking.

Comment: When compiling you can first "clean" the project (delete all previous compiler/linker output), then generate one object file per .c file, then simply check which ones that were generated.

Comment: Compiling is not an option because getting all the build dependency in order can be very hard and/or costly.
Using the dry-run with CMake leads to weird behaviour and fails also if the dependency are not set.

Comment: Re. `"...method which does not need to have a valid build environment"`.  But how can it be possible to know what build commands will be executed *without* a valid build environment?  This feels like an xy-problem.

Comment: Because I'm not directly interested in the _build commands_ per se but in the sources files dependencies. More precisely, I don't need to know that the option X or Y will be used when compiling foo.c, but to know that foo.c is used when compiling libfoo.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a solution to know which sources files are responsible/used for the creation of a specific binary without compiling the project itself

If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (or perhaps [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) you could use appropriate [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) like `-M` to generate and keep in some textual file the dependencies, in a format acceptable by [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or ninja build automation tools. This works well on Linux distributions like [Debian](https://debian.org/).

You could also be interested by other builders, including [omake](http://%20is%20there%20a%20solution%20to%20know%20which%20sources%20files%20are%20responsible/used%20for%20the%20creation%20of%20a%20specific%20binary%20without%20compiling%20the%20project%20itself), and package managers like [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/), [urpmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urpmi), etc...

You could also be in touch with [SoftwareHeritage](https://softwareheritage.org/) team.

If you use GCC, you could write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to maintain these dependencies in your database.

At last, be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), and think about crazy examples (in C++) like

```
   #if __TIME__[0]=='1'
   int something=0;
   #else
   constexpr int something=1;
   #endif
```

So my current intuition is that your wish is impossible. I could have misunderstood it.

Refer to some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), or to some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Study the behavior of tools like [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Think of programs *generating* C or C++ code like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c), [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), [SWIG](https://swig.com/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) .... Notice that [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) has many C++ code generators (notably [gengtype](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/gengtype)) and is definitely "a complex project coded in C++".

See also [linuxfromscratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).